# Angularjs Http Request change

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-promise

I need to append some value to my URLs which are having `/app` string on the front. Because this is the app someone has developed and we need to change URLs which I mentioned above.

Here is one of example URL which I need to change.

```
$http.post('api/account/createAccount')
```

I tried below, However, it didn't work.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
                return {

                    'request': function (config) {
                        var str = config.url;
                        if(str.search("/api") > 0 ){
                            config.url = "localhost:1337" + config.url;
                            return config || $q.when(config);
                        }

                    }


                }

            });
```

This is included in the config section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
         return {
             'request': function (config) {
                 if(str.indexOf(`/api` > -1) {
                     config.url += "localhost:1337";
                 }
                 return config;
             }

         }
     });
 });
```

Try this. Not sure what you're attempting to do here with `$q`

Answer (score 0):

You do not return config in some cases, that's wrong. You should modify your config in some particular cases, and in the rest return untouchable `config`.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
    return {
       'request': function (config) {
            var str = config.url;
            if (str.search("/api") > 0) {
                config.url = "localhost:1337" + config.url;
            }

            return config;
        }
    }

});
```